# Counting beads on a string

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a simple counting problem. The only solutions I've been able to come up with are very elaborate and ugly. I'm sure this problem has been solved with a simple, short formula, but I haven't been able to find it on the internet.

On a string divided into $n$ discrete sections, how many permutations of $x$ beads are possible if $x \le n$ and a bead can only be placed in one section at a time. In other words, you can slide the beads anywhere on the string as long as they each end up in one of the discrete sections. The string is not looped, and the beads can't be swapped into different positions.

The extension of this problem is summing all the answers for $x = 1$ through $x = n$.

I have only been able to solve this problem by summing all the possible bead positions for every value of x. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer. Thank you to Snufsan and everyone else for helping me see the incredibly simple and easy solution. I haven't thought about math in several years, so I'm a little rusty. The solution is just a straightforward binomial coefficient of $\binom{n}{x}$. The beads can't get out of order, so there are the same number of permutations as there are sets of beads when you choose $x$ from $n$.

Comment: I noticed that I misinterpreted your problem and provided a solution to a slightly different problem. The correct interpretation has a much simpler solution of which you've provided. In regards to summing all of these together, it is a well known result that $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} = 2^n$ which should help you with the last part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you, benguin. This is correct. I can confirm that the binomial coefficient works, and that your formula provides the correct answer for the summation problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to count this will be by looking at the beads as a given order (since we cant swap beads), and then insert separators for the discrete sections.

E.g. if we have $x$ beads and $n$ sections, we have $x+1$ possible places to put separators (between the beads and before the first\after the last bead), and $n-1$ identical separators to put with repetitions. So finally we come up with $$ {n-1+x+1 -1\choose n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $o$ denote a bead and $|$ denote a boundary of a section, notice that visually we see that we can represent a valid bead positioning as a sequence of $o$'s and $|$'s, e.g.,

$$oo|o||o,$$

Shows two beads in the 1st section, 1 bead in the second section, none in the third, and 1 bead in the last.

Notice that any permutation of the $o$'s and $|$'s give a valid bead positioning with 4 beads and 4 sections. Notice that if we pick the locations of the $|$'s in the sequence of $o$'s and $|$'s, then that uniquely determines a way of positioning the beads in each section. So the number of ways we can pick $3$ spots amongst the $7$ characters in the sequence is the number of bead positionings, in this case, $(\frac{7}{3})$. In general, if we have $n$ sections, then we will have $n-1$ $|$'s to place amongst the sequence of $x$ $o$'s and $n-1$ $|$'s (for a total of $n+x-1$ characters in the sequence) of which there are ${n+x-1 \choose n-1}$ ways.

You want to sum over all the choices of $x$, i.e., you want to figure out $\sum_{x=1}^n {n+x-1 \choose n-1}$.

There is an identity known as the hockey stick pattern  [(see here)](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Combinatorial_identity) in Pascal's triangle that states the identity,
$${n+1 \choose r+1} = \sum_{i=r}^{n} {i \choose r}$$

Manipulating our sum,
$$\sum_{x=1}^n {n+x-1 \choose n-1}$$
$$ = \sum_{x=n}^{2n-1} {x \choose n-1}$$
$$ = \sum_{x=n-1}^{2n-1} {x \choose n-1} - {n-1 \choose n-1} $$
$$ = \sum_{x=n-1}^{2n-1} {x \choose n-1} - 1 $$
$$ {2n \choose n} - 1.$$

To test this, consider $3$ sections:

**One Bead**

${3+1-1 \choose 3-1} = {3 \choose 2} = 3$ ways: $||o, |o|, o||$

**Two Beads**

${3+2-1 \choose 3-1} = {4 \choose 2} = 6$ ways: $||oo, |o|o, |oo|, o||o, o|o|, oo||$

**Three Beads**

${3+3-1 \choose 3-1} = {5 \choose 2} = 10$ ways: $||ooo, |o|oo, |oo|o, |ooo|, o||oo, o|o|o, o|oo|, oo||o, oo|o|, ooo||$

**Total**

$1+4+10 = 19$ ways

Comparing this with our formula,
$${2n \choose n} - 1 = {6 \choose 3} - 1 = 19,$$

which is consistent with what we saw earlier.

Comment: It turns out that my original interpretation of the problem is different than what was actually needed. I hope this answer is still helpful to some degree.